# Identify this tree with two different types of leaves?

Tags: identification, trees, leaves

There are 2 types of leaves sprouting from the mystery root here. You might guess that one is a sprig of tree leaves and the other leaves belong to a weed, but in fact both are growing directly from the root! In fact, the differing leaves even track back to the same stem. Can someone identify this tree, please? 
[image: Identification of same tree two types of leaves]

Our best guesses were some type of oak tree or a jacaranda tree, but we couldn't find any similar images on the Internet. There are many trees nearby, and unfortunately, I am not in the area, so I can't photograph them all for you.

UPDATED:

Ok, here are some photos of a young tree growing in my friend's backyard that looks to be the same species. You can't see the root clearly, but the leaf pattern is the same.

[image: young tree with two different leaves]

[image: young tree with two different leaves]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is some species of *Acacia*.

The strap-shaped leaves are actually petioles (the leaf stem) which have expanded and flattened, and do not have an actual leaf blade. This type of flattened petiole is called a phyllode.

The only acacia I've ever seen with these two different leaf forms is koa, but  several (maybe most?) Australian acacias also behave this way. It's been 20+ years since I've seen a koa, but if I remember correctly, the normal-looking compound acacia leaves are actually juvenile, and as the leaf matures and the phyllode develops, the leaflets fall off, leaving just the phyllode.

Here's a picture that demonstrates the growth habit of [*Acacia koa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acacia_koa):

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, Steve! I'm so glad to have this mystery solved.